# Selenium Grid Proxy: how to get the response after a command get executed

Tags: selenium-grid

I created a Selenium Grid proxy, I want to log every command done, the problem is I can't find a way to get the response of the command for example after "GetTitle" command I want to get the "Title" returned.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want this logging to be done ? If you attempt at logging this at the Custom Proxy, then these logs would be available only on the machine that runs the hub. Is that what you want ? If yes, then here's how you should be doing it :

Within an overloaded variant of `org.openqa.grid.internal.listeners.CommandListener#afterCommand` (this method should be available in your `DefaultRemoteProxy` extension object that you are building), extract this information from within the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` by reading its entity value and then translating that into a proper payload.

Here's how the `afterCommand()` (or) `beforeCommand()` method from your customized version of `org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy` can look like:

```
org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedResponse ar = new org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedResponse(response);
if (ar.getForwardedContent() != null) {
    System.err.println("Content" + ar.getForwardedContent());
}
```

If that's not what you want, then you should be looking at leveraging the `EventFiringWebDriver`. Take a look at the below blogs to learn how to work with the `EventFiringWebDriver`. The `EventFiringWebDriver` does not require customization at the Grid side, it just needs you to make use of the `EventFiringWebDriver` which would wrap within it an existing `RemoteWebDriver` object and the listeners you inject to it will help you get this.

- http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2011/02/generating-screen-capture-on-exception.html
- https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/eavesdropping-into-webdriver/ (This is my blog) Here I talk about not even using `EventFiringWebDriver` but instead work with a decorated `CommandExecutor` which would log all these information for you.

Comment: I want to do it in a custom proxy.
I have no problem with the request (which have the command type: click, url ..) but I can't get the response of that command, for example for getTitle command I want to access to the "title" returned.

Comment: @ElheniMokhles - I have updated my answer to show you code snippet of how to get this done.

Comment: I always get null when executing getForwardedContent() (both in beforeCommand and afteCommand)